# Получить значение тега P

Tags: jquery

Всем привет, есть такая верстка

```
 <a href="" class="s-block test1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
                                    <div class="s-img">
                                        <img src="images/s1.jpg" alt="">
                                        <div class="order">
                                            <p>Заказать услугу</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <p class="big">Уборка квартир1</p>
                                </a>

<a href="" class="s-block test1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
                                <div class="s-img">
                                    <img src="images/s1.jpg" alt="">
                                    <div class="order">
                                        <p>Заказать услугу</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <p class="big">Уборка квартир2</p>
                            </a>

<a href="" class="s-block test1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
                                <div class="s-img">
                                    <img src="images/s1.jpg" alt="">
                                    <div class="order">
                                        <p>Заказать услугу</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <p class="big">Уборка квартир3</p>
                            </a>
```

Как при нажатии на .test1 получить значение p.big

Answer (score 2):

В тегах указан jquery:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.test1', function(){
    let p = $(this).find('p.big').text();
    console.log(p);
    return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="" class="s-block test1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
                                    <div class="s-img">
                                        <img src="images/s1.jpg" alt="">
                                        <div class="order">
                                            <p>Заказать услугу</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <p class="big">Уборка квартир1</p>
                                </a>

<a href="" class="s-block test1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
                                <div class="s-img">
                                    <img src="images/s1.jpg" alt="">
                                    <div class="order">
                                        <p>Заказать услугу</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <p class="big">Уборка квартир2</p>
                            </a>

<a href="" class="s-block test1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
                                <div class="s-img">
                                    <img src="images/s1.jpg" alt="">
                                    <div class="order">
                                        <p>Заказать услугу</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <p class="big">Уборка квартир3</p>
                            </a>
```